# Cats Effect: Avoid calling unsafeRun on external listener of T => Unit

Tags: scala, scala-cats, side-effects, cats-effect

I am using external API which offers:

```
def listen(listener: ResponseType => Unit): Handle
```

My listener returns:

```
IO[Unit]
```

Is there a way to inject my listener without a need to call unsafeRun?

```
listen(msg => myListener(msg).unsafeRunSync())
```

Answer (score 2):

`IO` is not only container of your listener. From **cats-effect** documentation:

```
A pure abstraction representing the intention to perform a side effect, 
where the result of that side effect may be obtained synchronously (via return) 
or asynchronously (via callback)
```

it means `IO` contains not the some value but intention to perform some **side-effect**.

Here the most usual ways to work with `IO`:

1. Add some **effect** to the containing of `IO` using `flatMap` (this way named *composition*):

```scala
val ioA: IO[A] = ??? // you have some side effect returning A
// here you can have some different side effect returning B: work with DB, read some resource or so on
def aToIOB(a: A): IO[B] = ??? 
val ioB: IO[B] = ioA.flatMap(aToIOB)
```

2. **Launching** the whole chain of your combinations **side effects** from **1.** using `unsafeRunSync` or similar functions which run `IO`. It should be called once in your application and as a rule *in the end of the universe* (at the end of your program).

```scala
// this line launches execution of ioA and aToIOB and will return value of B with side-effects
val b: B = ioB.unsafeRunSync()
```

So when you see `IO[A]` you should remember that it is not the similar thing as `Option[A]` or `List[A]` and you can just execute `IO` to get `A`. You should use combination of `IO` while your application is not on the end of execution. If so you can run it using `unsafeRunSync`.

I mean you should build your application without using `unsafeRunSync` more than one time, and I guess, your signature

```scala
def listen(listener: ResponseType => Unit): Handle
```

should not use `IO` API, but very similar to `Async[F[_]]` API, take a look at function `async`:

```scala
/**
 * Creates a simple, non-cancelable `F[A]` instance that
 * executes an asynchronous process on evaluation.
 *
 * The given function is being injected with a side-effectful
 * callback for signaling the final result of an asynchronous
 * process.
 *
 * This operation could be derived from [[asyncF]], because:
 *
 * {{{
 *   F.async(k) <-> F.asyncF(cb => F.delay(k(cb)))
 * }}}
 *
 * As an example of wrapping an impure async API, here's the
 * implementation of [[Async.shift]]:
 *
 * {{{
 *   def shift[F[_]](ec: ExecutionContext)(implicit F: Async[F]): F[Unit] =
 *     F.async { cb =>
 *       // Scheduling an async boundary (logical thread fork)
 *       ec.execute(new Runnable {
 *         def run(): Unit = {
 *           // Signaling successful completion
 *           cb(Right(()))
 *         }
 *       })
 *     }
 * }}}
 *
 * @see [[asyncF]] for the variant that can suspend side effects
 *      in the provided registration function.
 *
 * @param k is a function that should be called with a
 *       callback for signaling the result once it is ready
 */
def async[A](k: (Either[Throwable, A] => Unit) => Unit): F[A]
```

Try to concentrate that `listen` should do in your application and choose correct signature.

Usefull links:

- [cats-effect IO monad](https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/05/02/io-monad-for-cats.html)
- [cats-effect Async typeclass](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/typeclasses/async)

Comment: The thing is, there is no way for me to change signature of listen. I can however change my listener (which saves data to DB using doobie).

Comment: @boneash I would recommend you write some adaptor to `listen` function using `Async`, my intuition tells me that in your case it would be the best decision.

Comment: or you can write little more about your root problem, maybe you doesn't see some oportunities to improve your code

Comment: I am using external lib provided by my company, it subscribes to rabbitmq messages of given type, not something I can easily change. I want to simply store the incoming message to DB when it arrives - lib will invoke the listener method I provide. The only possible type of the callback method is the one I wrote in the question. I am using doobie to store the data. Btw, calling `listen` simply hangs the execution so I run it in separate thread.